# What's the difference between programming in browser and WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I was just writing some codes in WebStorm, just like below

```
var cities = {
        resorts : ["new york", 'los angeles', 'san jose'],    
        print: (delay = 1000 ) => setTimeout(()=>{ console.log(this===window)})
}

cities.print()
```

In WebStorm, I expected that console printing out 'true' but it says `window` is not defined!

In the browser like Chrome, console printed out 'true'.

Isn't `window` the very antecedent object in js?

How can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window` object is only defined in browser, and isn't defined in Node.js environment. And it looks like you are running your code with Node.js (by choosing **Run** from the right-click menu of your `.js` file).

You need to include your javaScript code in `.html` file via `<script>` tag and then right-click this `.html` file in WebStorm and choose either **Run** or **Debug** to get the code executed in browser